# Woocommerce structure gone

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a weird problem. I was recently trying to install **SSL certificate** on my website, but it caused my **woocommerce sites** loose their **CSS connection** a look, well terrible. That is why **I undid the changes** (was simply by updating website adress in WP main configurations from *https* back to *http*.

Now, I have a different problem. The **Woocommerce sites have lost all their structures**. By that I mean, that for example generated category site looks like a blog. All the products look like empty blog posts even though all the typical woocommerce data has been untouched in the dashboard.

I quess I could export all the products and reinstall the Woocommerce Plugin, but It looks like it can be done by an easier fix.

Something is wrong with the paths...Don't know where and why. Haven't changed a thing in the plugin.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? Help will be greatly appreciated.

Best,

Stan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, i also faced this problem many times.
Usually, in our wp_options table we have to make sure these urls must be as our site urls.. Here is the attached screenshot:

[image]

Another is, sometimes, by updating these both urls, we got images, or some attachment's url broken, so for that i use: https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/ plugin to replace old urls with new ones, as old urls would be containing just http:// and now it must be replaced with https://. In this plugin url, some screenshots are also displayed, which will guide you how to update old urls. Make sure you take a backup of your databse before using this plugin to have a safe copy in case in problem after updating urls.

Comment: Thank You for the responce. I have checked and they match, as before.